# Custom models disappearing

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I'm using Parrot's Sphinx (https://developer.parrot.com/docs/sphinx/whatissphinx.html) which is based on Gazebo 7.
Somehow, when I add my own models, sometimes they disappear and collect themselves at (0,0).

There is no error / warning messages on the terminal.

Here's a video showing the issue:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cSCjNHOPNkI

This doesn't happen with the default models (tested with beer, cinder block, and cardboard box models).

What's happening???

Here's the sdf of one of my models;

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.5">
  <model name='tc6_big_target'>
    <link name='tc6_big_target'>
      <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
      <inertial>
        <pose>0.002502 0 0.50099 0 -0 0</pose>
        <mass>11.287</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>5.72909</ixx>
          <ixy>-1.72778e-18</ixy>
          <ixz>0.0282177</ixz>
          <iyy>5.65454</iyy>
          <iyz>-2.45135e-16</iyz>
          <izz>1.65105</izz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>
      <collision name='tc6_big_target_collision'>
        <pose>0 0 0 1.5708 -0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <mesh>
            <scale>1 1 1</scale>
            <uri>model://tc6_big_target/meshes/tc6_big_target.dae</uri>
          </mesh>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <visual name='tc6_big_target_visual'>
        <pose>0 0 0 1.5708 -0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <mesh>
            <scale>1 1 1</scale>
            <uri>model://tc6_big_target/meshes/tc6_big_target.dae</uri>
          </mesh>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
    </link>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

https://github.com/arixrobotics/tc6_models/tree/master/tc6_big_target

What am I doing wrong here?

Arif

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/22981/custom-models-disappearing/) by [arifrahman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5559/arifrahman/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-06-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [winston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1084/winston/) on 2019-06-20**:
Probably there is something wrong in your sdf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Whenever this happend to me, the problem was the physics configuration of the model. If you set extreme values (too big or too small) the physics engine will run into some computational problems.

How did you arrive to the inertia matrix for the model? Look at every place where you set some physics parameter (mass, inertia, friction, force limits etc.) and check, whether it might cause problems to the physics engine.

---

Originally posted by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) with karma: 755 on 2019-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arifrahman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5559/arifrahman/) on 2019-06-20**:
The issue seems to disappear after removing the < pose > element under < inertial >. Probably exactly as what you @kumpakri mentioned.

Anyway, I got the inertia matrix as a result of converting the Solidworks model into sdf, as shown in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkEyL1UWDNI